# Redirect from my server to Flickr

Tags: html, redirect, flickr

I want to have people who go to a web address on my server to be automatically redirected to one of my Flickr albums instead. I've tried embedding the code provided by Flickr, and I've also tried putting a redirect in an .htaccess file. These both lead to the Yahoo login, rather than my public album. Can anyone tell me how I can get this simple redirection to work?

Comment: If you're using PHP `<?php header('LOCATION:https://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/flicker'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

in script on the page you want to redirect people *from*

`window.open('Site or html page with your Flickr album here');`

Hope this helps!